# NullPointerException room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i have been struglling with null pointer run time error in my android project using room database.
when i try to save new row in my database it works but the error appears when i want to display the rows.

also i tried to open my database folder using DB BROWSER nothing appears in my database even tabels. it says 0 tabels. it's confusing me like nothing appears in my database but i can insert and delete from android studio project.

my logs

```
2021-11-22 19:12:29.020 3322-3353/com.example.roomproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.roomproject, PID: 3322
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.roomproject.MainActivity$onCreate$2$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "Users_Information")
data class User (
    @PrimaryKey val id:Int,
    val name:String
        )
```

Dao interface
@Dao

```
interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertUser(user:User)

    @Delete
    fun deleteUser(user:User)

    @Query("DELETE FROM Users_Information")
    fun deleteAllNotes()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users_Information ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getAllUsers():LiveData<List<User>>
}
```

Database builder class

```
@Database(entities = [User::class],version = 1)
abstract class UserDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dao():UserDao

    companion object{
        private var userDB:UserDB? = null
        @Synchronized
        fun getDatabase(context: Context):UserDB{
            if(userDB==null){
                userDB = Room.databaseBuilder(context,UserDB::class.java,"PLEASE")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
            return userDB as UserDB
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val edId = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ed1)
        val edName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ed2)
        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val btn2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)


        btn.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                UserDB.getDatabase(applicationContext).dao().insertUser(
                    User(edId.text.toString().toInt(), edName.text.toString())
                )
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Sved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        btn2.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val list = UserDB.getDatabase(applicationContext).dao().getAllUsers().value
                for (i in list!!)
                    Log.d("awawd", i.name)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Android Studio give you warning for not using `GlobalScope`?

Comment: I guess the problem is where you use `getAllUsers().value`. The LiveData returned by Room doesn't contain the data initially. You should `observe` that LiveData and update UI accordingly. Or if you don't want live updates, just make `getAllUsers` function suspend and directly return the list without wrapping it inside LiveData.

Comment: the problem is not only restricted on reading data from database. as i mentioned tables are not even created when i viewed my database in DB BROWSER

Comment: Do you see the toast message "Sved"?

Comment: yes i can see save message

Comment: IIRC The tables are created right when you open the database for the first time. What do you have in line 39 in MainActivity?

Comment: Log.d("awawd", i.name)

Comment: I guess it would be `for (i in list!!)`. You are getting error because of `!!` as `list` is null initially as I mentioned in my comment above